# Get last backup date of SQL Server database when the db name of the backup file does not match the database

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Due to an oversight, my database backups don't have a transaction log, but I have full backups at five-day intervals.  In order to do some revision of the current version of the database, I've restored each of these backups to separate databases each named with the format `<dbname><backupdate>` where `<dbname>` is the name of my database.

I need to find the backup date associated with each database programmatically where I can't assume the format of the database names.  Since `<dbname><backupdate>` (the name of my databases) doesn't match `<dbname>` (the database name in the backup files), I can't use the query I've found on several other pages:

```sql
SELECT d.name, b.backup_start_date
FROM sys.databases d
LEFT OUTER JOIN msdb..backupset b ON d.name = b.database_name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, I discovered, lies in the `msdb..restorehistory` table.

```sql
SELECT d.name, MAX(b.backup_start_date) backup_date
FROM sys.databases d
JOIN msdb..restorehistory r ON r.destination_database_name = d.name
JOIN msdb..backupset b ON r.backup_set_id = b.backup_set_id
WHERE d.database_id > 4 -- for excluding system databases
GROUP BY d.name
ORDER BY backup_date, d.name
```

This will only return databases that were restored from a backup.  If you want to include all non-system databases, change the `JOIN` statements to `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.